# SSL Client Certificate with Puma

Tags: ssl, aws-api-gateway, puma, client-certificates

Our Rails servers are behind AWS Gateway API. We intend to use its client ssl authentication so they are accessible only via the Gateway address. We want to throw out every request not coming from the AWS Gateway. But... for now our servers are running on Puma (not nginx).

Is there way to start puma with ssl_client_certificate flag?

Something like

`puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt'`

but for client certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question

`puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt&ca=ca.key&verify_mode=force_peer'`

Or in puma.rb

`bind 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?verify_mode=force_peer&ca=certs/ca.key&key=server.key&cert=server.crt'`

The missing argument was `verify_mode=force_peer`